# Как быть когда в админки Джанго выпадающий список разрастается до огромных цифр

Tags: django, django-admin

на примере тренировочной базы данных бойцов UFC

```
class Fighter(models.Model):
name=models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Имя бойца', unique=True)
CHOICES = [
    ('male', 'Мужской'),
    ('female', 'Женский')
]
gender=models.CharField(max_length=7,verbose_name='Пол', choices=CHOICES)
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural='Бойцы'
    verbose_name='Боец'
    ordering = ['name']
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В итоге список может разрастись до 1000 бойцов. А в ручную это будет нереально неудобно искать и выбирать. Как быть в такой ситуации? Может есть атрибут упрощающий выбор нужного человека из другой таблицы БД?

Comment: [autocomplete_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) в админке

Comment: Спасибо огромное)))